# Possible to change Messages up/down key behaviour?

Tags: keyboard, messages, keybindings, text-editor

In most single-line text edit fields, pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> moves the cursor to the start of the line, and pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> moves the cursor to the end. But in the Messages app, the behaviour is slightly different; it seems to consider 3 positions: the start of the line, something like the last location of the cursor, and the end of the line, and pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> cycles through these (so e.g. pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> then <kbd>↓</kbd> returns the cursor to the same position).

I can see some logic to this for people who press <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> accidentally and want a quick way back to their old place, but I find it jarring since I'm used to the standard home/end behaviour. Is there a way to configure it? I'm not sure if this is Messages-specific, or something more general (though I haven't seen any other apps show this behaviour).

Demonstration of different behaviours (if the video doesn't play, click it to open in a new window; seems Imgur prevents looping gifs):

[image: Demonstration of different behaviours]

Comment: as some extra fun, it seems that sometimes (perhaps after deleting?) this middle position it returns to isn't even the last cursor location, so I'm thinking this is probably a bug in the Messages text editor rather than an intended feature

Comment: This is likely because TextEdit is a macOS app and Messages is an iPad app. Could file a bug report (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) but otherwise nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

Up/down arrow is 'previous line/next line'. It will use the same position in the line, if such exists; once at the top or bottom line it will then become 'home & end' but only in that one instance. On a single line edit field you're actually seeing 'odd behaviour' because there is no last or next line. Messages displays regular, correct, multi-line behaviour.

The standard keys for 'beginning or end of line' are  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>  or  <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: I have updated the question with a video demonstrating the different behaviours I see. Notice that the Messages behaviour is inconsistent with all other types: single-line fields, multiline fields with one line of text, and multiline fields with multiple lines of text.

Comment: I can't tell from that.